# Capistrano bundle install trying to install development gems on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, capistrano3

I have a development gem that is trying to be installed on the server via capistrano and is failing b/c i'm pointing to github at the moment.

Why is this gem trying to be installed on my server anyways?

Gemfile snippet:

```
gem 'capistrano-local-precompile', '~> 1.0', :git => 'git@github.com:stve/capistrano-local-precompile.git', :branch => 'cap3', :group => :development, require: false
```

Capistrano snippet output:

```
00:08 bundler:install
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.3 do bundle install --path /var/www/csmschedule/shared/bundle --without development test --quiet --no-cache
      01 The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be established.
      01
      01 RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `GIT` section for `capistrano-local-precompile` present in your Gemfile.lock, and is that lock file committed to your repo? In other words, have you run `bundle install` locally, committed both `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, and pushed those changes before running `cap deploy`?

Bundler needs to know the dependencies of the `capistrano-local-precompile` gem in order to do version resolution. Even if you specify `--without development`, it still needs this information (because version requirements of development gems can affect version resolution for production ones).

If your lock file is not present or if it is out of date (i.e. `capistrano-local-precompile` is not in the lock file), then Bundler needs to download the gem from GitHub in order to update the lock file.

On a related note: I notice you are not using `--deployment` in the bundle command on the server. That is probably not a good idea. You should use `--deployment` so that Bundler checks that your Gemfile.lock is up to date, as described here:

http://bundler.io/v1.15/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE